# Applications of Sard's theorem?

Tags: measure-theory, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I'm writting an essay for University about differential topology. In particular, I'm studying the applications of Sard's theorem on differential topology. I have included the proof of Whitney's embedding theorem and some results about transversality (stability and genericity), but I would like to study one more application.

Could anyone give me any suggestion? Thank you

Comment: Existence of Morse functions

Comment: Mod 2 Intersection theory. Anything in guillemin and Pollack basically.

Comment: Can you show me your essay?